# Any PHP editors supporting 5.3 syntax?

Tags: php, ide

I'm using namespaces in a project and Eclipse PDT, my IDE of choice, recognizes them as syntax errors. Not only it renders its convenient error checking unusable, but it also ruins Eclipse's PHP explorer.

5.3 features are coming to PDT 2.0 scheduled for release in December. Are there any alternatives for the present moment? I'm looking for 5.3 syntax highlighting and error checking at the least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some threads that have been addressed by the various PHP IDE developers regarding the status of 5.3 syntax support:

- **PHPEclipse**: http://www.phpeclipse.net/ticket/636 or [google](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=php+5.3+phpeclipse)
- **Aptana**: http://forums.aptana.com/viewtopic.php?t=6538 or [google](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=php+5.3+aptana)
- **PDT**: http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=234938 or [google](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=php+pdt+5.3)
- **TextMate**: http://www.nabble.com/PHP-Namespace-Support-td19784898.html (Namespace support) or [google](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=php+pdt+5.3)

Answer (score 2):

This [blog](http://spektom.blogspot.com/2009/03/php-53-support-in-pdt-2nd-stage-is-over.html) states that PHP 5.3 support already presents in [latest integration](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/) of PDT 2.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

NuSphere (http://www.nusphere.com/ ) just released PhpED with full support for all php-5.3 features. Works great for me.

-j

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of netbeans 6.8(beta) does support most of the new features...

Answer (score 1):

I'm finding JetBrains php storm pretty good.

Comment: JetBrains phpStorm editor is the right choice

Comment: Actually, using it a little bit more I found a few problems with name resolution and inheritance, I don't recall them now exactly, I believe it was something like this: lets say you have a class B extending class A. A has a constant C (A::C), then if you wanted to use B::C it would show an error, which is really annoying.

Comment: ZendStudio 8 is also a good one, but not free.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Aptana Studio or the Aptana plugin for Eclipse? I'm not sure if the Aptana plugin supports PHP, but Aptana Studio does. That might have what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It probably won't really help you, but my current solution is Zend Studio 5.5 with real-time errors disabled. I can't use the internal debugger on 5.3 projects, but everything else in the IDE still works and the namespace code isn't highlighted as an error. I get to keep the code explorer and syntax highlighting and just test my code external to the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

jEdit http://jedit.org